# Get Numpy ndarray value from list of nd points

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

How can I obtain value of a ndarray from a list that contains coordinates of a n-D point as efficient as possible.

Here an implementation for 3D :

```py
1    arr = np.array([[[0, 1]]])
2    points = [[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
3    values = []
4    for point in points:
5        x, y, z = point
6        value.append(arr[x, y, z])
7     # values -> [1, 0]
```

If this is not possible, is there a way to generalize lines 5-6 to nD?

Comment: does `arr[*point]` work?

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix this was my first guess, but no. This is syntactically not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Numpy documentation for indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html?highlight=indexing#dealing-with-variable-numbers-of-indices-within-programs), you can easily do that, as long as you use tuples instead of lists:

```py
arr = np.array([[[0, 1]]])
points = [(0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0)]
values = []
for point in points:
    value.append(arr[point])

# values -> [1, 0]
```

This works independent of dimensionality of the Numpy array involved.

Bonus: In addition to appending to a list, you can also use the Python [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) function to extract ranges directly:

```
arr = np.array([[[0, 1]]])
points = (0, 0, slice(2) )

vals = arr[points]
# --> [0 1] (a Numpy array!)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am sure there is way to achieve this using fancy indexing. Here is a way to do without the for-loop:

```
arr = np.array([[[0, 1]]])
points = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]])
x,y,z = np.split(points, 3, axis=1)
arr[x,y,z]
```

output (values):

```
array([[1],
       [0]])
```

Alternatively, you could use tuple unpacking as suggested by the comment:

```
arr[(*points.T,)]
```

output:

```
array([1, 0])
```